# How to determine if SQL Server Reporting Services database is being used?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

I have a SQL 2005 server that needs to be decommissioned. For regular databases, I have a couple scripts that look at sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to determine last access. My normal process is to make sure the last access date is back quite a while, then take offline and wait to be sure there are no problems before taking a final backup and then deleting the database.

However, since ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB are associated with SSRS, should they be treated differently? Is there an easier way to tell if SSRS is in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExecutionLog databases seems to be the way to go:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RptExecutions
FROM     ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog
        ,ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog2
        ,ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog3
```